# OpenMP double reduction with nested for loops

Tags: c, openmp

I started to learn OpenMP and I can not deal with this code. It gives different results each time it runs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    int numsmp = 10;
    double d = 0.0;
    double d1 = 0.0;
    float trace[10];
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) reduction(+ : d, d1)
    for (int i = 0; i < numsmp; i++) {
        for (long int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            printf("\n");
            d++;
            printf("i  = %d k = %d d = %lf", i, k, d);
        }
        d1 += d;
        trace[i] = d;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\n%lf", trace[i]);
    }
    printf("d1=%f\n", d1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I will note that on my machine it seems to give consistent (but obviously wrong) results (60 rather than 110) - but this can be different of different machines, it can also depend on the current system load.

Your issue is that you are using one of the reduction variables `d`, to calculate the other. An OpenMP reduction will create a local variable for each thread (in this case each thread will have a local `d` and `d1`) and sum them together in the end.

In your case, if you run this without sequentially, you will be summing the following values of `d` to `d1`: `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20`, but if you run it with 2 threads (who, let's assume, share the load evenly) each of them will sum the following values of their *local* `d` to their *local* `d1`: `2, 4, 6, 8, 10`. After that, the code will sum the local `d1` of each thread to give you the final result.

To check our reasoning, we can try the sums ourselves, the single-threaded sum should give us 110 and the code does too. Using 2 threads should then (assuming even load distribution) should give us 2x30=60, which again, it does.

I'm going to assume this is simply a very nice minimal example, so I can not suggest how you should go about solving whatever it is you wish to do. But in this case, you could simply calculate `d` from `i`. If such a thing is not possible (in some other case), you can use `critical` regions, but those are not always a good solution (depends on the problem).

Further reading on reductions can (for instance) be found here: http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-reduction.html